# azure blob premium storage vs standard storage

Tags: azure, azure-storage, azure-blob-storage, azure-virtual-machine

I want to use the premium storage for better performance.

**I am using it for BLOBS and i need the fastest blob access for reading.**

**I am using the reading and writing of the blobs only internally within the data center**

I create a premium storage and checked it vs the standard storage by reading a blob of 10 MB 100 times in different location using seek method (reading 50 kb each time).

I read it using a VM machine with windows server 2012

the result are the same - around 200 ms.

Do i need to do something else ? like attach the storage ? if so how do i attach the storage.

both the vm and the storage are at the same region

Comment: Main purpose of Premium storage is to store VHDs for your Virtual Machines for faster disk access. It is not meant for reading blobs using REST API. Are you using it for VMs?

Answer (score 3):

You can use Premium Storage blobs directly via the REST API. Performance will be better that Standard Storage blobs. Perf difference may not be obvious in some cases if there is local caching on the application or when the blob is too small. Here 10MB blob size is tiny compared to the performance limits. Can you retry with a larger blob? Like, 10 GB? Also note that Premium Storage model is not optimized for tiny blobs.

Comment: Also note that you can only use premium storage with page blobs. (like the VHD files people keep mentioning). For block blobs (general files), you have to use standard storage.

Answer (score 0):

Well, in Virtual machine cases it always rely on your main Physical HDD, unless you will used that premium storage it's plus but i think internet connection matters as well.

Answer (score 0):

By default, there is **a temporary storage(SSD)** provided with each VM. This temporary storage drive is present on the physical machine which is hosting your VM and hence can have **higher IOPS** and **lower latency** when compared to the persistent storage like data disk.

[image]

For test, we can create a VM with HDD disk, and attach a SSD to this VM. After it complete, we can install some tools to **measure disk performance**, in this way, we can find the difference between HDD and SSD.

> like attach the storage ? if so how do i attach the storage.

We can via Azure new portal to attach a SSD to this VM.

[image]

[image]

More information about attach disk to VM, please refer to this [link](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/virtual-machines/virtual-machines-linux-attach-disk-portal).

Comment: i have read this post regarding blobs: 
https://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/pricing/details/storage/blobs/
 and 
https://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/pricing/details/storage/unmanaged-disks/.

what i need as i mention is the fastest blob access. 

so do i need to attach the premium storage to my VM ? i don't understand...

Comment: access from the internet? or internal?

Comment: only internal. i need the blob reading to be as fast as possible

Comment: I see,  I think you should create a SSD VM.

Comment: When you create your VM via the portal, select disk type to SSD.

Comment: but i need around 10 TB of ssd - so i need to create 10 disks and attach them?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/138791/discussion-between-jason-ye-msft-and-asaf).